# Can I run different logic for a function returning reference depending on whether it's used as lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, value-categories

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  int x;
  int& val() { 
    return x; 
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.val() = 2;
  int y = foo.val();
}
```

In the main function, `foo.val()` is sometimes used as lvalue and sometimes as rvalue.  I would like to to put logic inside the definition of `val()` function depending on how it's being used. Is that possible?

Comment: I think not possible, but a better answer might be: why? Are you sure this is not the result of a design flaw or a misunderstanding of how the language works? (I'll refrain from calling this an XY problem since you are looking at possibilities rather than assuming this is a solution.) **Note:** *There might be a good reason for this. I am aware of an argument for something like this involving `operator[]`. Still, let's make sure the motivation is good.*

Comment: Maybe, a simple design is to define 2 separate accessors: ```int Get_X()```, and ```void Set_X( int input)```.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with an existing framework. I wasn't involved in the design decision but I'm fairly certain that there are very good reasons to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the main function, foo.val() is sometimes used as lvalue and sometimes as rvalue. I would like to to put logic inside the definition of val() function depending on how it's being used. Is that possible

There is no straightforward way to do what you want.

However, you *could* wrap the integer inside a wrapper class and use the conversion operator `operator int&` and `operator=` to achieve what you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct Wrapped {
        std::reference_wrapper<T> x;
        Wrapped(Wrapped<T> const& rhs) : x(std::ref(rhs.x.get())) {
            std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
        }
        Wrapped(T& x) : x(std::ref(x)) {}
        Wrapped<T>& operator=(T const& a) {
            std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
            x.get() = a;
            return *this;
        }
        operator T&() {
            std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
            return x.get();
        }
    };
    Wrapped<int> x_w = Wrapped<int>(x);
public:
    int x;
    Wrapped<int>& val() {
        return x_w; 
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.val() = 2;      // lvalue
    int y = foo.val();  // rvalue
    auto z = foo.val(); // rvalue
}
```